# Starting an Erlang slave node in escript fails when using custom Erlang in Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: ubuntu, erlang

I have the following escript:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%%! -name test_starter@127.0.0.1

main(_) ->
    NodeName = test,
    Host = '127.0.0.1',
    Args = "",

    {ok, _Node} = slave:start_link(Host, NodeName, Args),
    io:format("Node started successfully!").
```

When running it on Ubuntu 10.04 I get this:

```
$ ./start_slave
Node started successfully!
$
```

I want to install my own Erlang (latest version, debug compiled files for dialyzer etc) since the stock install of Erlang on Ubuntu lacks some features. I put my Erlang binaries inside `~/Applications/bin`. Starting Erlang normally works, and starting slave nodes inside an Erlang shell works as well.

However, now my escript doesn't work. After about 60 seconds it returns an error:

```
$ ./start_slave                                   
escript: exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,timeout}
```

Even if I change the first line to the escript to use my erlang version, it still does not work:

```
#!/home/user/Applications/bin/escript
```

The slave node is started with a call to `erlang:open_port/2` which seems to be using `sh` which in turn does not read my `.bashrc` file that sets my custom `PATH` environment variable. The timeout seems to occur when `slave:start_link/3` waits for the slave node to respond, which it never does.

*How can I roll my own installation of Erlang and start slave nodes inside escripts on Ubuntu 10.4?*

**Update:** I've tried to add the path to my custom Erlang inside `/etc/environment` (where the original `PATH` in Ubuntu is set) but this does not change anything...

**Update 2:** Accepting the only answer given (even though it didn't solve the problem). The Ubuntu and Erlang versions are a bit old now and this might not be an issue anymore.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `start_link` instead of `start`? This way, your slaves automatically quits when your script terminates itself (which appens, after main has been called). See the docs for `start_link` for this.

Comment: The point is that the node starting times out even before `start_link/3 returns'.

Comment: Also, the point is to run tests, so I'm okay with the node dying when the script dies. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that the slave node is being run with the other Erlang install?  Listed under reasons for timeout error in [the documentation on slave nodes](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/slave.html) I saw "the Erlang nodes have different cookies" which might, I believe, occur in that case.

If this were the case, running `ps -FC erlang` while it's waiting for the timeout should show you processes with different paths.

Comment: It actually doesn't start, or crashes immediately upon starting. I can't see a process for the slave node.

Comment: In any case, it should use the same cookie since I have it set in `~/.erlang.cookie`

Comment: Accepting this answer since no other answer has been given. Never found out how to solve the problem though. :-(